# php remove empty elements, but dont remove '0'

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove empty elements from my array.

I found this code for that :

```
$outaa = array_map('trim', $outaa);
$outaa = array_filter($outaa);
```

My array contains elements whose contain '0' only.
My code removes those elements too which only have '0' in it.
but i dont want to remove those.

Comment: Define empty. `"", 0, 0.0, "0", NULL, FALSE, array()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$outaa = array_remove_empty($outaa);


function array_remove_empty($arr){
        $narr = array();
        while(list($key, $val) = each($arr)){
            if (is_array($val)){
                $val = array_remove_empty($val);
                // does the result array contain anything?
                if (count($val)!=0){
                    // yes :-)
                    $narr[$key] = $val;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (trim($val) != ""){
                    $narr[$key] = $val;
                }
            }
        }
        unset($arr);
        return $narr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

array_filters removes empty elements in the non-strict sense. Ie it will remove 0, '', null, array(), etc.

You have to use a function that does strict comparison. I assume that "empty" meant null and that you have PHP 5.3+ (for the use of closures):

```
$outaa = array_filter($outaa, function($element) { 
    if($element !== null) return true;
});
```

Or if you don't have 5.3 use a normal callback:

```
function filter_empty($element) 
{ 
    if($element !== null) return true; 
} 
$outaa = array_filter($outaa, 'filter_empty');
```

Comment: Error : PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /var/www/server/rcon.php on line 29

Comment: You can also do this with a normal callback instead of a closure:

`function filter_empty($element) { if($element !== null) return true;
}
$outaa = array_filter($outaa, 'filter_empty');
`

That will work with earlier vbersions of php.

Answer (score 0):

One-liners are always nice. The following will remove all empty strings, `NULL`, and `FALSE` elements from an array:

```
$clean_array = array_diff(array_map('trim', $my_array), array('', NULL, FALSE));
```

**Explanation:**

- **1st parameter of `array_diff`:** The trimmed version of `$my_array`. Using `array_map`, surrounding whitespace is trimmed from every element via the `trim` function. It is good to use the trimmed version in case an element contains a string that is nothing but whitespace (i.e. tabs, spaces), which I assume would also want to be removed. You could just as easily use $my_array for the 1st parameter if you don't want to trim the elements.
- **2nd parameter of `array_diff`:** An array of items that you would like to remove from `$my_array`.
- **Output:** An array of elements that are contained in the 1st array that are not also contained in the 2nd array. In this case, because `''`, `NULL`, and `FALSE` are within the 2nd array, they can never be returned by `array_diff`.

**EDIT:**

It turns out you don't need to have `NULL` and `FALSE` in the 2nd array. Instead you can just have `''`, and it will work the same way:

```
$clean_array = array_diff(array_map('trim', $my_array), array(''));
```